# How do I make my urlpatterns smarter, to avoid cumbersome code in my templates?

Tags: django, url, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Right now I have defined my URLs such that they can include different combinations of category (always on), attribute_slugs (1 and/or 2) and brand_slug, all using the urlpatterns defined below.

In my views.py file I make sure that each slug exists in the respective model, or else a 404 is thrown. I also make sure that the attributes have a specific ordering, so that I avoid identical pages where the attributes are just switched around in the URLs. Then the context is sent to a template.

In my template for the categories, I implement an ecommerce filter based on the context. For example, the filter can show links to the attributes contained by the products on that particular page. So if you are on the page: /shoes/, then the color filter has the options: /shoes/green, /shoes/blue/, /shoes/black/ etc. This filter is made with the default { % url % } template tag with parameters based on the context.

It works fine, but there is one issue. It is based on *a lot* of logical statements in the template, which is cumbersome. For example, there is an if-statement to check if there is 0 attribute, 1 attribute and 2 attributes on the current page. I also check the same for brands, meaning there are a lot of if-statements in the template (remember they multiply). I have to do this, because I need to write different versions of the { % url % } template tag based on the context of the page. Specifically, the parameters of the template tag changes based on the page.

For example, if a given page does not include any attributes, then the clickable URL to any attribute must be: {% url 'products:product_categories' slug=category.slug attribute_slug=*ATTRIBUTEVALUE* %}. In other words: Only the first attribute_slug is set.

On the other hand, if the page has one attribute already, then the ordering of the new and the old attribute is checked to see which one comes first, and then the new attribute is added in the URL, like this: {% url 'products:product_categories' slug=category.slug attribute_slug=*ATTRIBUTEVALUE* attribute_slug2=*ATTRIBUTEVALUE2* %}.

Now, this seems relatively simple when I explain it like this. But there are a lot of different cases that makes this more cumbersome, for example also considering the brand_slug, and considering that I also have functionality used to remove a particular attribute or brand from the URL.

So finally, my question is; **Is there a better approach urlpatterns and dynamic parameters in template URL tags?**

One thought I have myself is to pass an abitrary number of arguments in the URL template tag (like the **args or **kwargs in classical pythonic). This would look similar to this: {% url 'products:product_categories' *KWARGS %}. I just really havn't found a way for this to work.

Is there anything smarter you can think of?

Thanks in advance, and best regards.

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
        # Category + Attributes
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){1}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){1}/(?P<attribute_slug2>[\w-]+){1}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
    
        # Category + Brand + Attributes
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<brand_slug>[\w-]+)/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<brand_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){1}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
        re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<brand_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){1}/(?P<attribute_slug2>[\w-]+){1}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"),
    ]
```

Comment: Do these entities have to be in the URL, or can you use `request.GET` to gather a querystring `http:/.../vk/thing?attr=attrval&brand=somebrand&category=one&...` When redirecting you do have to urlencode the querystyring and appemd it to the result of reverse.

Comment: They have to be in the URL, which is why I haven’t “just” used classical filters with query parameters :-)

Comment: If you can identify appropriate delimiter characters you could pack everything into a single parameter and "decode"/"encode" it easily using string methods split and join. E.g. `http:/.../vk/attr:attrval;brand:somebrand;category:one;...`  Any use?

Comment: @nigel222, That's not a bad suggestion! The attributes will always be seperated by "/", so I guess I can split by this in the view, and do the 404 checks for each split up value. And I could also send the seperated values as context to the template.

Comment: I see some immidiate disadvantage, though. That is, I will have to search for each split up value in each possible model (attribute or brand for now), and it will also require the values to be unique across the models. This could be fine, though, as I don't think brands and attributes will overlap in values. Do you see any other drawbacks to the solution? I'm trying to consider pros and cons :-))

Comment: I don't have enough insight into your environment. However, if you use CBVs you might implement a site-wide plugin or customized base View, which decodes any keyword argument with a particular name into (say) self.params (some sort of dict) and provides a method for re-encoding the (possibly modified) contents thereof (for redirections, etc.) thereby minimizing coding and code repetition.

Comment: Main drawback I can imagine is if you go down this route and then some <marketing person> decides that ":1;2" absolutely has to be a valid category! Or similar.

Comment: I am using CBV, and with a lot of logic in there already for context data. I see, I am that marketing person, as it's a one-person project for now hehe. But I'll keep clean names for categories. Do you have an input to the right regex in the urlpatterns for this solution? For now, I have come up with the following (next comment):

Comment: re_path(r"^vk/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){0,3}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"). This seperates category and attributes, but it creates two ending "//" when there is no attribute_slug.

Comment: re_path(r"^vk/(?P<attribute_slug>[\w-]+){1,4}/$", ProductCategoryListView.as_view(), name="product_categories"). This could work. It combines categories and attributes, which I guess there is not a reason to seperate, as long as I can seperate them after the split in the CBV (note: I always want category or brand first, else 404)

Comment: I'd parse out anything that's guaranteed to be present and just collect everything else in a single <str:otherparams>. Then, inject code into my CBVs (setup method subclass?) to create self.params (always? or only if the kwarg "otherparams" is present? ). You might start self.params=self.kwargs.copy() and then update it with your decoded otherparams, and never reference self.kwargs in your subsequent code. Once again, I don't have any insight into your environment.

Comment: It's actually a considering, because in this case there is always either productcategory or brand in the beginning, so either of those. By the way, would you benefit from writing your answer as an "actual" answer to this question? Then I can choose you as correct answer - if it somehow benefits you here on Stack Overflow :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing up the above discussion as suggested.

For whatever reason, passing the parameters as GET parameters with a querystring is ruled out. They have to be in the URL.

My suggestion is then to parse only the constant parameter(s) in the URLconfig. For the others, roll them up into a single string parameter by imposing a syntactic restriction on what values they can and cannot have. Something like `http://.../attr:attrval;brand:somebrand;category:one;...` parsed as, say, otherparams.

To minimize code duplication thereafter, it would be possible to write a common code Mixin for all class-based views which are going to use this technique. Subclass the `setup` method:

```
class OtherparamsMixin( object):
    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        super().setup( request, *args, **kwargs)

        self.otherparams = {}            
        if 'otherparams' in self.kwargs:

             params = self.kwargs['otherparams'].split(';')
             for p in params: 
                  k, v = p.split(':',1)
                  self.otherparams[k] = v
```

and then any view defined with this Mixin will have `self.otyherparams` automagically available for use

```
class SomeView( OtherparamsMixin, CBVclass):
```

and for commonly-used CBV classes one can define base classes including the mixin:

```
class SiteFormView( OtherparamsMixin, FormView):
    pass
class SiteListView( OtherparamsMixin, ListView):
    pass
```

etc. and then use these instead of the standard CBVs.

For redirecting, it may be useful also to inject a method for converting a dict representation of a set of `otherparams` back into a text string:

```
    @staticmethod
    def otherparam_str( otherparams):
        p = []
        for k,v in otherparams.items():
             if ";" in v:
                 raise ValueError( f'Semicolon not permitted in an otherparams value, but found "{k}" with value "{v}" )
             p.append( f"{k}:{v}" )
        return p.join(";")
```